# WCF DataContract centralization

Tags: wcf, soa

I have several WCF services that use the same dataContracts to interchange data between them.

Can I have a sort of Metadata Endpoint for centralizing the management of all this schemas?

When creating a new WCF service, how can i make it to load the schemas from the Metadata Endpoint (instead of redefining them) to use inside its operationContracts?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you're looking to use the same Data Contracts between multiple services, just put them into a separate assembly and have each service reference that assembly.

Comment: What do you mean by: Metadata endpoint ? and Centralizing the management of all this schemas? what is your schema ? what is Centralizing a management ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment, I'm not sure I understand your question (at least with regards to wanting a metadata endpoint), but it sounds like you want to have the ability to reuse existing data contracts in multiple different services.

The easiest way to do that is to put the data contracts in a separate assembly (class library - DLL), and then have the services reference that assembly - they don't have to be defined inside the service itself.

Here's a trivial example (code is for illustration only, not intended to actually do anything or be a complete sample):

MyDataContracts assembly

```
namespace MyDataContracts
{

    [DataContract]
    public class DataContract1
    {

    }

    [DataContract]
    public class DataContract2
    {

    }
}
```

MyService1 assembly

```
using MyDataContracts;

namespace MyService1
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        DataContract1 GetSomeData(string someParm);
    }   
}
```

MyService2 assembly

```
using MyDataContracts;

namespace MyService2
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService2
    {

        [OperationContract]
        void SendSomeData(DataContract1 dc);

        [OperationContract]
        DataContract2 GetSomeOtherData(int parm);
    }
}
```

Of course, each of the WCF service projects will need to include a reference to the MyDataContracts assembly as well.

Now whenever you create a new service, you simply add a reference to the MyDataContracts.dll and you can reuse your data contracts in it.

Comment: Agreed, and then from the client us ChannelFactory [1] with the contracts in that shared assembly and avoid Add Service Reference entirely.

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734681.aspx

Comment: @kellyb - Yes, if the service contracts are in shared assemblies.  Data contracts shouldn't factor in for ChannelFactory.

Comment: Thanks! i made a mistake when using the WCF kewyord. Suppose you have one team implementing a service in wcf, and the other in Java. The shared dll approach wont work. i want to be able to centralize the contract definition in a platform independent way.